# update metadata of files inside SPFolder using C#

Tags: 2013, 2010

I am trying the below code but it throws error

```
SPFolder movedFolder = oWeb.GetFolder("FolderPath");
                            foreach (SPFile file in movedFolder.Files) {
                                file.CheckOut();
                                file["ListID"] = NewItemID;
                                file.Update();
                                file.CheckIn("Updated", SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);

                            }
```

It shows error at `file["ListID"] = NewItemID;`

I want to update the ListID property of the existing files in SPFolder

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SPListItem listItem = file.Item;
    listItem["ListID"] = listID;
    listItem.Update();
```